# Getting "SessionOptions.CookieName is obsolete" in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've recently upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2. The site uses session, but after I upgraded I get:

> "SessionOptions.CookieName' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete
>   and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative
>   is Cookie.Name."

What is the new way to implement session?

Current implementation, **Startup.cs** (**ConfigureServices**):

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.CookieName = ".Smokers.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
});
```

**Startup.cs** (**Configure**):

```
.
.
.
app.UseSession();
```

Comment: *What is the new way to implement session?* It literally says *The recommended alternative is Cookie.Name* https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/257

Answer (score 7):

> What is the new way to implement session?

From reading the error message...

> "SessionOptions.CookieName' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is Cookie.Name."

...it seems like you want to use `Cookie.Name`.

> ## [Unifying API for configuring cookie settings](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/257)
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
> {
>     services.AddSession(options =>
>     {
>         // obsolete
>         options.CookieName = "SessionCookie";
>         options.CookieDomain = "contoso.com";
>         options.CookiePath = "/";
>         options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
>         options.CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
>         // new API
>         options.Cookie.Name = "SessionCookie";
>         options.Cookie.Domain = "contoso.com";
>         options.Cookie.Path = "/";
>         options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
>         options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
>     });
> }
> ```